# Getting IllegalStateException : Session/EntityManager closed exception when running IntegrationTests while running fine with normal app run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, mockmvc

**First Problem**

In my application I am creating a Criteria (`java org.hibernate.Criteria`) like this,

```java
@Service
public class ReportsUtil{
    // some fields

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "logs")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Criteria createCriteriaFromSession() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        return session.createCriteria(RunningHistoryRdbmsModel.class);
  }

    public Criteria formCriteria(){ 
        Criteria criteria = createCriteriaFromSession()
        // operations on criteria
        return criteria;
    }

}
```

which I am using later in this app.
This code is working fine when I am run my application but throws *IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available* when I run integration test.
Here is my Integration test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ReportRDBMSIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    ReportsUtil reportsUtil;

    @Autowired
    ReportRDBMS reportRDBMS;

    @Test
    public apiTest(){
        // some tests
        Criteria criteria = reportsUtil.formCriteria();  // throws IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available here 
        String res = reportRDBMS.executeQueryForSuccess(criteria);

    }
}
```

When running this test it throws *IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available.* There are no stack trace but I found out the error to be comming from `ReportsUtil` on line `Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);`

**Second Problem**

I researched and found out that `@Transactional` can be a solution to my first problem above so I used that annotation on `ReportsUtils` class like so,

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class ReportsUtil{
    // same code as above
}
```

Now I have a function inside class called `ReportRDBMS` which is using Criteria formed by `formCriteria()`, here is the class:

```java
@Service
public class ReportRDBMS {

    public String executeQueryForSuccess(Criteria criteria){
        // operations on criteria
        List<String> result = criteria.list(); // throws IllegalStateException : Session/EntityManager closed.
        // using result
    }
}
```

After using `@Transactional` I am not getting *IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available.* at `Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);`, but now I am getting *IllegalStateException : Session/EntityManager closed* at `List<String> result = criteria.list();`, when I am running integration test.

Can someone tell me the cause of these problems and solution for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is you want a full integration test, launch the server, but manually trigger things. Make your test `@Transactional` to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you tell what was causing this issue briefly.

Comment: The absence of an enclosing transaction.